# Crontab not work

Tags: cron, fedora

I have a crontab in fedora 17 with command

```
13 10 * * * /home/pk1/Templates/dump.sh
```

In dump.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
mysqldump --host=localhost --user=root --password=toor mba_new | gzip > /home/pk1/Templates/`date +"webt-backup_%m-%d-%y"`.gz
```

In log file have an error

```
Mar 25 10:13:01 area7 crond[31770]: (*system*) RELOAD (/etc/crontab)
Mar 25 10:13:01 area7 crond[31770]: (CRON) bad command (/etc/crontab)
```

if I run through terminal

```
sh dump.sh
```

everything is ok

Why my dump.sh not work through crontab? Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your crontab needs a username Please specify it as

```
13 10 * * * pk1  /home/pk1/Templates/dump.sh
```